# Trajectory Splicing Error

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I am trying to send my Staubli TX90 robot arm a Joint Trajectory command which publishes to /joint_path_command, which the motion_streaming_interface node subscribes to. My code complies and build correctly, but when I run the node, there is an error saying "Trajectory splicing not yet implemented, stopping current motion." I looked online and noticed that:

```
// read current state value (should be atomic)
int state = this->state_;

ROS_DEBUG("Current state is: %d", state);

if (TransferStates::IDLE != state)
{

if (msg->points.empty())

ROS_INFO("Empty trajectory received, canceling current trajectory");

else

ROS_ERROR("Trajectory splicing not yet implemented, stopping current motion.");

     this->mutex_.lock();

trajectoryStop();

     this->mutex_.unlock();

return;
```

This is my code for the node that I am running to communicate with the robot arm and subscribe to `/joint_states` and publish to `/joint_path_command`:

```
using namespace std;

sensor_msgs::JointState JS;

void jointStateCallback(const sensor_msgs::JointState msg) { JS = msg; }

int main(int argc, char** argv) { 
  ros::init(argc, argv, "mover_node");

  ros::NodeHandle n;
  ros::AsyncSpinner spinner(1);
  spinner.start();

  bool success;

  ros::Publisher joint_pub = n.advertise<trajectory_msgs::jointtrajectory>("/joint_path_command", 1);
  ros::Subscriber joint_sub = n.subscribe<sensor_msgs::jointstate>("/joint_states", 1, jointStateCallback);
  ros::Rate rate(10.0);

  trajectory_msgs::JointTrajectory JT;

  JT.joint_names.clear();
  JT.joint_names.push_back("joint_1");
  JT.joint_names.push_back("joint_2");
  JT.joint_names.push_back("joint_3");
  JT.joint_names.push_back("joint_4");
  JT.joint_names.push_back("joint_5");
  JT.joint_names.push_back("joint_6");

  JT.points.resize(2);
  JT.points[0].positions.resize(JT.joint_names.size());
  JT.points[1].positions.resize(JT.joint_names.size());

  while(ros::ok()) {
    
    if(JS.position.size() != 0)
    {
      cout << JT << endl;
      
      JT.points[0].time_from_start = ros::Duration(0.0001);
      JT.points[0].positions = JS.position;
      
      JT.points[1].positions[0] = 0.0;
      JT.points[1].positions[1] = 0.0;
      JT.points[1].positions[2] = 0.0;
      JT.points[1].positions[3] = 0.0;
      JT.points[1].positions[4] = 0.0;
      JT.points[1].positions[5] = 0.0;
      JT.points[1].time_from_start = ros::Duration(1);
          
      joint_pub.publish(JT);
    }
    rate.sleep();
  } 
  ros::shutdown();

  return 0;
}
```

The values of the JT object are:

header:

seq: 0

stamp: 0.000000000

frame_id:

joint_names[]

joint_names[0]: joint_1

joint_names[1]: joint_2

joint_names[2]: joint_3

joint_names[3]: joint_4

joint_names[4]: joint_5

joint_names[5]: joint_6

points[]

points[0]:

```
positions[]

  positions[0]: 0.883191

  positions[1]: -0.00796466

  positions[2]: -0.0596276

  positions[3]: 3.05678

  positions[4]: -0.00680966

  positions[5]: 0.0617737

velocities[]

accelerations[]

effort[]

time_from_start: 0.000100000
```

points[1]:

```
positions[]

  positions[0]: 0

  positions[1]: 0

  positions[2]: 0

  positions[3]: 0

  positions[4]: 0

  positions[5]: 0

velocities[]

accelerations[]

effort[]

time_from_start: 1.000000000
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/301266/trajectory-splicing-error/) by [shreyasgan](https://answers.ros.org/users/36895/shreyasgan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 26 on 2018-08-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> but when I run the node, there is an error saying "Trajectory splicing not yet implemented, stopping current motion

the `industrial_robot_client` nodes don't support trajectory splicing (blending or stitching of subsequent trajectories).

You'll have to make sure that the previous trajectory has finished before sending a new one.

The `/joint_path_command` topic accepts trajectories, not single points, so sending it new trajectories at 10 Hz like the code does that you show will not work.

---

> so I am just trying to send a simple command to my TX90 robot arm, which has ROS integration. My final goal is to send a set of predefined waypoints to a cartesian planner, and publish that trajectory to the TX90 arm (end effector control).

Then create a single trajectory with as many points as you need (but know that dense trajectories typically result in slower motion). Send that complete trajectory in one msg to the `/joint_path_command` topic.

Or make use of the action server that is started by the driver launch file. That would accept [FollowJointTrajectory](http://docs.ros.org/api/control_msgs/html/action/FollowJointTrajectory.html) actions, which are a little friendlier in use than a raw topic. For one thing, they would allow you to wait for trajectory execution to complete, and notify you when that happens.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-08-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [shreyasgan](https://answers.ros.org/users/36895/shreyasgan/) on 2018-08-23**:
Okay, so I would have to make the JointTrajectory points in my JT object have more than one set of points, or add a velocity parameter to the JT message I publish to motion_streaming_interface? Also is it necessary to make the first set of joint positions in the trajectory equal to th current state?

**Comment by [shreyasgan](https://answers.ros.org/users/36895/shreyasgan/) on 2018-08-23**:
I have now updated my code to send a Joint Trajectory message with two sets of points, yet I am still getting the same Trajectory splicing not implemented Error. I have also added the values of the JT object. Any help is greatly appreciated.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-08-24**:
You're still sending trajectories at 10Hz to the driver. You have to check whether the previous trajectory has finished executing. If it hasn't and you set a new one, you'll get that error.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-08-24**:
Perhaps it would be good if you can provide a little more information on what it is that you're trying to achieve. Right now we're focusing on a very specific detail of an approach that might not be appropriate for what you're trying to do.

**Comment by [shreyasgan](https://answers.ros.org/users/36895/shreyasgan/) on 2018-08-24**:
Alright, so I am just trying to send a simple command to my TX90 robot arm, which has ROS integration. My final goal is to send a set of predefined waypoints to a cartesian planner, and publish that trajectory to the TX90 arm (end effector control).

**Comment by [shreyasgan](https://answers.ros.org/users/36895/shreyasgan/) on 2018-08-24**:
Thank you! The code works now that I have removed the rate(10.0) line. I was wondering, how would I send an end effector trajectory (computed by a cartesian planner) to one of the topics that industrial_robot_client subscribes to, when it only subscribes to topics that use Joint Trajectory messages